# A crash/mini dump concern

Tags: windows

I just experienced a crash on my laptop.

I was surfing the internet and all of a sudden everything crashed and a small blue screen (centred on the screen) popped up and was counting down. I didn't have a chance to get a photo.

It rebooted and upon restarting and logging in, a "windows" window popped up describing the `unexpected shutdown` event.

The name of the "Problem Event Name" is BlueScreen. It also provides OS version, Local ID, BCcodes, BCP1 etc and a location of the `.dmp` file.

To provide some scope, I'm on a Macbook Pro running Windows 7, dual booted on a partitioned hard drive. Been using the laptop like this for 2 years.

Should I be concerned? Is there anything I can do to prevent it happening again?

As far as I can tell, everything loaded ok. I'm typing this now using the system. Thanks.

Comment: The most likely problem may be due to faulty RAM, run hardware diagnostics to verify it.